# How to set up the launch order Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I need to re-do the setup with every thread(number). Now I have 2 times first the setup thread, and then 2 times the main thread. In setting apply 2 threads in SetUp and Main

The problem is that I end up getting requests with the same JSESSION ID

I want to see like this->

First thread:

1. CSRF-TOKEN
2. LOGIN
3. Test(first csrf login)

Second thread:

1. CSRF-TOKEN
2. LOGIN
3. Test(second csrf-token)

I know that this can be done in one thread, but there can be many such requests. And so we need a single setup, so as not to duplicate
[image]

---

UPDATED:

changed my code like you said and now it doesn't work.

I use in postprocessor this code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;
import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.Cookie;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.PropertyIterator;
import org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.JMeterProperty;

CookieManager manager = ctx.getCurrentSampler().getCookieManager();
PropertyIterator iter = manager.getCookies().iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        JMeterProperty prop = iter.next();
        Cookie cookie = prop.getObjectValue();
          if (cookie.getName().equals("JSESSIONID")) {
            vars.putObject("JSESSIONID", cookie);
               break;
              }
         }
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        JMeterProperty prop = iter.next();
        Cookie cookie = prop.getObjectValue();
          if (cookie.getName().equals("XSRF-TOKEN")) {
            vars.putObject("XSRF-TOKEN", cookie);
               break;
              }
         }
```

This Preprocessor main thread:

```
CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
manager.add(vars.getObject("JSESSIONID"));
manager.add(vars.getObject("XSRF-TOKEN"));
```

But now it doesn't work

I used to use:

```
props.put("JSESSIONID", cookie);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correctness of your test design is a big question mark, normally you don't need to pass any data between thread groups.

However if you've been told to do so by your not very competent team lead looking at my crystal ball I can see the following possible problems:

1. If you're using something like `props.put("property-name", vars.get("csrf-token"))` you're **overwriting the previous value with the next value** on each occurrence/iteration because [properties are **global**](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for the whole JVM process. Consider using [ctx.getThreadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContext.html#getThreadNum()) as the property prefix/postfix
2. If you're using something like `props.put("property-name", "${csrf-token}")` the [first occurrence of variable is being cached](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and used on subsequent iterations. Consider using [`vars.get("csrf-token")`](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#get(java.lang.String)) instead

More information on these `ctx`, `vars` and `props` guys: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes)

Comment: Im updated post. Please help me

Comment: Im doesnt have team lead from experience. I study and understand myself